# Convolution from a geometrical perspective

Tags: calculus, integration, area, convolution

I have seen lots and lots of questions about convolution here, however I have not seen one addressing my specific doubts.

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Visual_explanation) on convolution, has a section on visualizing the function:
[image]
[image]

At the beginning of the document it claims:

> In mathematics (in particular, functional analysis) convolution is a mathematical operation on two functions (f and g) that produces a third function expressing how the shape of one is modified by the other

I am especially focused on `function expressing how the shape of one is modified by the other`.

I understand this wording is meant more as a high level "wishy washy" description than it is about any formalization, however I am trying to understand the properties of convolution as function mixing operation.

To give a clear example of what I mean, linear interpolation is an easy concept. It "mixes" 2 functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that the resulting function $g$ is "$1-x$ percent $f_1$ and x percent $f_2$"

In this same spirit, I am trying to understand how convolution "modifies one function through the shape of another".

Naively I first thought that convolution describes the overlapping areas of the functions as one is slided over the other. I got this from the visual explanation. However the claim that the yellow area is the area of overlap of the 2 functions at time $t$ doesn't seem correct. This is only true if one of the 2 functions is a box function with height 1.

Other wise $$\int_a^b f(\tau) g(t - \tau)d\tau$$ discretized as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n f(\tau_i^*)g(t-\tau_i^*)\Delta\tau$$

Can't possibly be the area, since the overlapping area wouldn't be the product, it would be $min(f(\tau_i^*), g(t-\tau_i^*)) \Delta\tau$ which just happens to be equal to the product when one of the functions is a box function with height 1. Thus the diagram's explanation is somewhat misleading.

Thus I am still not sure about how a convolution merges the shapes of the images. Computationally, what it is doing is fairly straightforward, I am not making a question about *what* a convolution is, but about *how* convolutions manipulate their input functions.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: The wikipedia animation is a pathological example where $f$ is a function of unit height, so $f(\tau)g(t-\tau)$ exactly corresponds to the area under $g$. Whereas in general, the product of the two functions will give "the product area" under the two functions, which generally isn't exactly the area under $g$.

Comment: The discrete version $\sum f(\tau_i) \Delta\tau g(t-\tau_i)$ can be treated as a weighted addition of functions, $g(t-\tau_i)$, placed at different locations. For example, if $g(t)=1/\Delta\tau$ with a compact support $[-1/2\Delta\tau,1/2\Delta\tau]$, then $\sum f(\tau_i) \Delta\tau g(t-\tau_i)$ is in some sense a discrete approximation to continuous $f(t)$. This is like doing a piece wise constant approximation to $f$. When $g(t)$ is compact, one can think in these lines.